# not finding rails asset index file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two index files in my rails assets directory

app/assets/some_feature/
  index.js

app/assets/lib/my_library
  index.js

if I do a 
  = require some_feature

it finds the some_feature/index.js file just fine

If I do a 
  = require lib/my_library

it will not find lib/my_library1.3/index.js

If I do a 
  = require lib/my_library1.3/index.js

all works well.

In otherwords for the index.js that is nested inside lib/my_library1.3 I have to explicitly name the index file to get it to load.

Is this expected?  I would think I could just reference the library and away I go.

Rails 3.2

Comment: I assume you meant that `require lib/my_library1.3` doesn't work. Presumably this is because it thinks the `.` is denoting an extension and therefore is looking for a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the "dot" in the name prevents rails from finding the index.  Why I don't know